# Custom numbering in revealjs quarto

Tags: quarto

In a quarto presentation, I'm using `number-sections: true` to activate the numbering of `h1` slides:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
format:
  revealjs:
    number-sections: true
    number-depth: 1
---

# chapter 1
```

[image]

However, how could I customize the numbering, so it appears as `1) chapter 1`, or even `Section 1: chapter 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use css for that:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
format:
  revealjs:
    number-sections: true
    number-depth: 1
---


<style>
.header-section-number:before {
  content: "Section ";
}
.header-section-number:after {
  content: ":";
}
</style>

# chapter 1
```

[image]